# Where to put templates and static assets for deployment

Tags: django

Where should I put all my static assets for deployment? Currently I have this in my settings.py

```
if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static_only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
    )
```

Here's my directory structure on my local machine:

```
├── env       
├── src    
|   ├── esp_project
|   ├── reports
|   └── templates
|       ├── registration
|       └── reports
└── static
    └── static
        └── css
        ├── js
        └── img
```

From the docs I understand they should be served by apache2, not by python. Could someone clarify this? And what about templates, are those in the "right" place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your templates you can make a new folder in you main static directory.

In your settings.py you can set the path like this.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static', 'templates'),
    )
```

You can also add in template loaders to your settings.py.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (

    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

)
```

Now Django will look in `static/static/templates` for your templates (which are static files).

The rest looks good just make sure you have `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` above `if Debug:`

See: [Django Project Loading Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loading-templates)

Comment: Why do I want TEMPLATE_LOADERS ?

Comment: django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader 
Loads templates from Django apps on the filesystem. For each app in INSTALLED_APPS, the loader looks for a templates subdirectory. If the directory exists, Django looks for templates in there. --- Sorry misread your question the first time